# append to collabsible content after the header?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

i am running into problem, concerning append. i ve a dynacmic collabsible, which i fill with a dynamic list. i want to append this list after the header h3 of the collabsible.
when i append it to the collabsible, it does not appear in the

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed"> </div>
```

but after. therefor i get a space between the content header and the list, which i want to avoid.
i tried this:

```
$('some-selector > ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed') but it does not work.
```

any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to append inside

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed"> </div>
```

Then you should use:

```
$('div.ui-collapsible-content.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed').append($content);
```

Where `$content` is either a jQuery object, a DOM element or a HTML string. Note the `.` in the selector, which specifies a class (or two).

See [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: this worked for me $(this).find('div.ui-collapsible-content.ui-collapsible-content-  collapsed') but hte margins are still far away: think i ve to work on the css